# Setting the min frame size via NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

For reasons that are out of scope of this question (see below), I want to set the window's frame minimum size to a certain size. Introducing `NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor` works and I see it run through its `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`.

In it, I am iterating over the windows and set their size as well as a `NSWindowDelegate`. I tried `contentMinSize` as well as `minSize`, but neither seems to work, as I can shrink the size *below* my specified size.

Here's `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`:

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    for i in 0..<NSApp.windows.count {
      NSApp.windows[i].delegate = windowDelegate
      NSApp.windows[i].setContentSize(NSSize(width: 1440, height: 900))
      NSApp.windows[i].contentMinSize = Constants.minSize
      NSApp.windows[i].minSize = Constants.minSize
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here–why is neither `NSApp.windows[i].contentMinSize = Constants.minSize` nor `NSApp.windows[i].minSize = Constants.minSize` working here?

Here's the complete sample app's code:

```swift
import OSLog
import SwiftUI

@main
struct so_20240112_WindowMinSizeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, idealWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, minHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, idealHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

extension Logger {
  static var adHoc = Self(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "adhoc")
}

final class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  let windowDelegate = WindowDelegate()
  enum Constants {
    static let minWidth = 1280.0
    static let minHeight = 800.0
    static var minSize: CGSize {
      CGSize(width: self.minWidth, height: self.minHeight)
    }
  }

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    for i in 0..<NSApp.windows.count {
      NSApp.windows[i].delegate = windowDelegate
      NSApp.windows[i].setContentSize(NSSize(width: 1440, height: 900))
      NSApp.windows[i].contentMinSize = Constants.minSize
      NSApp.windows[i].minSize = Constants.minSize
    }
  }
}

final class WindowDelegate: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate {
  func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let currentWindow = NSApp.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) {
      Logger.adHoc.debug("Current size: \(currentWindow.frame.width) x \(currentWindow.frame.height)")
    }
  }

  func windowDidBecomeKey(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let currentWindow = NSApp.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) {
      Logger.adHoc.debug("Current min size: \(currentWindow.minSize.debugDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

### TL;DR

The reason I want to set the min size like this is that I was hoping to be able to be able to control opening the frame size of a new window a user adds: I want to enable the user to resize the window to whatever they like (just not below the minimum) and **additional windows to open in that size**.

Unfortunately, SwiftUI's `frame(minWidth:idealWidth:maxWidth:minHeight:idealHeight:maxHeight:alignment:)` won't let me do this as it will always use the `minWidth` and `minHeight` instead of their ideal versions (which I would set to the last user's resizing).